# elasticsearch throw exception work with mongodb river

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I followed the link http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/ElasticSearch-and-Mongo-DB-td4033358.html to integrate elasticsearch and mongodb using mongodb river. The versions of each component are:

- ubuntu 12.04 64bit
- ES 0.90.0
- mongodb 2.4.3
- river 1.6.5

Mongodb is standalone running in one server but according to this link http://loosexaml.wordpress.com/2012/09/03/how-to-get-a-mongodb-oplog-without-a-full-replica-set/, the oplog is opened as replSet and oplogSize is configured in /etc/mongodb.conf, and the db.oplog.rs.find() also displayed some operation records.
The index added by:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_river/appdata/_meta -d'
{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb" : {
    "db": "test_appdata",
    "collection": "app_collection"
  },
  "index": {
    "name": "test_appdata",
    "type": "app"
  }
}'
```

But when the elasticsearch started, the log show some exception as follow:

```
[2013-05-07 23:20:40,400][INFO ][river.mongodb            ] [Ransak the Reject] [mongodb][app] starting mongodb stream. options: secondaryreadpreference [false], throttlesize [500], gridfs [false], filter [], db [test_appdata], script [null], indexing to [test_appdata]/[app]
Exception in thread "elasticsearch[Sundragon][mongodb_river_slurper][T#1]" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetResponse.exists()Z
    at org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver.getLastTimestamp(MongoDBRiver.java:1088)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver.access$2200(MongoDBRiver.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver$Slurper.getIndexFilter(MongoDBRiver.java:967)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver$Slurper.oplogCursor(MongoDBRiver.java:1021)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver$Slurper.run(MongoDBRiver.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

I'm a newbie to elasticsearch and mongodb, is the replica setting of mongodb caused the error? 
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your river is not compatible with Elasticsearch 0.90.
Move to ES 0.20.6 or ask for a patch in Mongodb river Project.

Comment: I upgrade the river to 1.6.6, it worked correctly. And here is the compability list of river & es & mongodb, https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb. Thank you!